# when to use fallback functions and know when to use them in nodejs

Tags: node.js

when I am listening on the server

```
var http=require('http');
var host ='127.0.0.1';
var port = '3000';

var server = http.createServer((request,response)=>{
    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
    console.log('server is working');
    response.end("server is working");
});

server.listen(port,host,(error)=>{
    if (error){
        return console.log('some errors',error);
    }
    console.log('server is listening on '+ host);
});
```

What does this part mean ?

```
(error)=>
```

How am I supposed to know when to use them ?

Comment: The last parameter to [server.listen](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlisten) is a callback function added as a listener for the 'listening' event. It's provided inline as an arrow function in your example.